# AZURE Hosting & MVC5 Reporting

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, reporting-services

I am developing an MVC5/EF6 web application hosted on Azure using Visual Studio 2013. I have just got to the portion of development whereby I need to create the reports. I was trying to use Microsoft.ReportViewer to achieve this and although it works perfectly locally it would appear that the WOW (WAWS) on a standard Azure website does not have/allow enough privileges to generate/return a PDF via a stream reader (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/b4a6eb43-0013-435f-9d11-00ee26a8d017/report-viewer-error-on-export-pdf-or-excel-from-azure-web-sites?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview). The suggestion from Microsoft was to convert the web site to a web role - I am prepared to do this however it seemed like a "no go" for most contributors - also I cant find any tutorials on the matter (I have posted a new question on this).

My question is, what are my options? SSRS is being deprecated so a server call is out, hand cranking a HTML page does not appeal. The closest I have found to a solution breaks the MVC pattern, but should work see here:
[Rendering an RDLC report in HTML in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991167/rendering-an-rdlc-report-in-html-in-asp-net-mvc)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a web role to gain access to GDI+ and elevated WOWs rights, from there I was able to export directly to PDF which is just what I wanted. Not sure why so many other articles condemned this it seems to work perfectly and the cost differentiator does not seem too bad... yes it is more - however, experiments with the extra small VM has proved quite successful.