# How To Convert An Existing MVC5 Website To Web Role

Tags: azure

I have created an MVC5/EF6 website which is running on Azure - I have hit a problem on the reporting side ([AZURE Hosting & MVC5 Reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21669522/azure-hosting-mvc5-reporting)) with one possible solution being to create a web role?

Is it as easy as creating a web role project and adding my existing project to it? What do I need to do on the Azure side of things or will it just work?

Thanks in advance!

David

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have Windows Azure SDK .Net for Visual Studio 2013 installed, easiest way would be to right click on the web project, click on `Convert` and then choosing `Convert to Windows Azure Cloud Service Project` as shown in screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Excellent! Thank you! That converted the project! Now to understand the difference between the two and try to get my reports working!