# SQL Server Reporting solutions that don't require self-hosting

Tags: sql-server, azure, reporting-services

I'm working on a multi-tenant SPA application that will be hosted in Azure and will store data (via API) in an Azure SQL Database.

I now need to add the equivalent of SSRS but we would like a fully hosted service rather than having to manage servers ourselves.  My understanding is that even with SSRS, we would be required to manage a VM and would be responsible for security updates, upgrades, etc. -- something we're trying to avoid.

In my scenario, the users don't need to create reports -- the developer with create the reports.  The users only need to be able to run the reports and print/save them as PDF or export them in CSV or Excel format.

Are there any kind of options for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using WebForms you can develop reports locally without SSRS and use the report control to display it and offer PDF and CSV options.  The reports are local to your project and have the RDLC extension instead of RDL extension which runs with an SSRS server.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio-18001

If using MVC, there is no control to use so you have to resort to handling running the report and displaying to the browser which there are many samples out there that should be able to help you get going like:

[MVC 5 How to use an object in rdlc report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39042863/mvc-5-how-to-use-an-object-in-rdlc-report)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HBXTUFmQ0UA

Or

Hack in a WebForms page with MVC, something like:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/rdlc-integration-in-mvc-application-report-display-using-iframe/

OR

[ReportViewerForMvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ReportViewerForMvc/) nuget package that promises to do this for you and a [sample](http://www.aspmantra.com/2017/08/asp.net-mvc-create-rdlc-report-aspmantra.html) using it.

Comment: @CSharpRocks - Yes, nothing special going on in these cases that Azure websites/app service wouldn't allow to my knowledge.  Do you know of something that wouldn't allow this?